# Infinite series of transcendental numbers

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that there is an infinite series of transcendental numbers which converges and that all the terms of the series are positive. Would the limit of the series be transcendental as well? For consider the following example:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^4}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^4}...}}$

Comment: Hint : Consider $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e\cdot j!}\cdot $$

Comment: $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n\pi)^2}$$ is a series of positive transcendental terms with rational limit. In your example, we know that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational, but as far as I'm aware not whether it is transcendental.

Comment: @lulu We had almost the same idea almost simultaneously :)

Comment: Consider $\sum \frac 1e\times \frac 1{n!}$

Comment: @Peter  True!  Though my first series had negative terms, but I think the second one works.

Comment: First, I made a mistake, but yes, it should work , if I did not miss something.

Comment: Certainly the sum of some transcendental numbers will again be transcendental (*e.g. $e+e=2e$*).  In other cases we don't know if some sums of transcendental numbers are transcendental or not (*e.g. even $e+\pi$ has not been proven yet to be transcendental*).  On the other hand there are absolutely some sums of transcendental numbers which are not transcendental (*e.g. $e + (3-e) = 3$*).

Comment: @JMoravitz But we need a counterexample for an infinite sum.

Comment: Still my example is false since we have to start with $0$ , unfortunately, I cannot edit it anymore.

Comment: And those have already been given in the comments.  My point was that the intuition leading to this conjecture seems flawed in the first place, likely having originated from the flawed assumption that "transcendental + transcendental = transcendental" which is incorrect even in the finite case.  An infinite counterexample could also be crafted using the $e+(3-e)=3$ type if one desires having adjacent terms in the series have substantial cancellation into something more well known.

Comment: @Jmoravitz The problem with pairwise cancelling terms is that the series does not converge, viz: $\sum_i (-1)^i$. If the transcendental part of any one term disappeared iff its cancelling counterpart is included, you in effect have defined a new series that has only non-transcendental terms.

Comment: @KeithBackman you lack imagination or are too focused on the fact that simplifications can be made.  Let $t$ be your favorite transendental number between $0$ and $1$.  Then $(1+t)+(1-t)+0.1(1+t)+0.1(1-t)+0.01(1+t)+0.01(1-t)+\cdots = 2 + 0.2 + 0.02 + 0.002 + \cdots=\dfrac{20}{9}$  The sum on the far left can in fact be considered a sum of only transcendental numbers.  Yes, the sum on the right happens to not include any (*and also converges to a rational number*) but that is irrelevant to the fact that the sum on the left was as requested a sum of only transcendental numbers.

Comment: If your complaint is that I used associativity here before proving that the original sum should converge as well (*just as using associativity on $\sum (-1)^i$ is flawed*), that is easily addressed by using various well known theorems on the topic such as dominated convergence theorem etc... to first show that it must converge, and then using the above associativity argument that not only does it converge that we know what it actually converges *to*.

Comment: I guess my complaint was that starting with a convergent series $\sum (a_i)=k$, it seems that morphing it into $\sum (a_i+(-1)^it)=k$ is essentially a trivial exercise that does not address (what I perceive to be) the inquiry posed (and for which I have no answer).

Comment: I agree that it is a trivial exercise, however I do insist that it *does* address the inquiry.  "*Is such and such true*", "*No, here is a trivial counterexample.*"  It shouldn't be discarded just because of its triviality.  The question was if *every* convergent sum whose summands are all transcendental result in a transcendental number to which the trivial sum I propose above (*as well as the earlier examples*) should clearly show the answer is "no, it is possible for it to converge to an algebraic (even a rational) number" (though it is also possible to converge to another transcendental)